# 4 buttons in 4 corners of the screen

Tags: html, css, button, position

I am working on a school project, and i need to place 4 buttons in the 4 quadrants of the screen. However, the first button has a little gap between it and the top of the screen as well as the side.

Code:

game.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<button class="button">A</button>
<button class="button">B</button>
<button class="button">C</button>
<button class="button">D</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

game.css

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
h1, h2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
}
.button: nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #bf0000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.button:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #001fbf;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.button:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #e6c52d;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.button:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #1fbf1f;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

However, i get the output shown here:

[image: output]

How can I remove the gap at the first button?

(and if you want, help me with the color :D)

Any help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo within CSS.

```
.button:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #bf0000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Remove the space after .button:

Comment: OMG THANK YOUUUUU I AM SO STUPIDDDD